# ERROR 14908 o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter Failed to configure a DataSource:

Tags: java, spring

```
2021-03-09 12:02:48.045  WARN 14908 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties$DataSourceBeanCreationException: Failed to determine a suitable driver class
```

I wants to start first project at spring boot. Unfortunately, an error appears:
[o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IxwF6.png)

What am I doing wrong? I googled this error, unfortunately, I found nothing.

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class VotingsystemApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(VotingsystemApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

Comment: It failed to load dataSource, do you have dataSource? show your relevant properties?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I seems that you are missing the Hikari Driver depedency. Maybe adding it to maven will help:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.zaxxer</groupId>
  <artifactId>HikariCP</artifactId>
  <version>3.4.5</version> 
</dependency>
```

But if you want a more qualified answer you will have to share more of your config and properties.